# How to delete the internal link tag from the website url after refreshing the webpage

Tags: php, url, redirect, hyperlink, internal

In my website I use internal links, but I want to delete the internal link tag from the url. For example my link is example.com/help.htm#top, how do you delete/remove the #top after reloading the webpage? I hop you can answer this question without redirecting the link.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: ow kk, but do you have an answer ;)

Comment: If I had the answer, then surely I know how to click the "Post your answer" button.

Comment: You're pretty grumpy today, why don't follow a rainbow ;)